# Two Different Websites List Different Expense Ratios - Which One Can I Trust?

Tags: expenses, expense-ratio

I'm trying to find VXF's expense ratio.

- [Finance.yahoo.com](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pr?s=VXF%20Profile) says that it is .10%.
- [Seeking Alpha](http://seekingalpha.com/symbol/vxf) says that it is .16%. (and I suppose that I should consider that a tracking error of .11% further separates me from the index that it's supposed to track).

Which expense ratio number can I trust?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I find it best to go to [the horse's mouth](https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/snapshot?FundId=0965&FundIntExt=INT#hist=tab%3A3) (i.e. the company that operates the fund, in this case Vanguard):

> Extended Market ETF   0.16%